# Turn off autosave in Visual Studio 2019 16.8.4

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

When I change tabs (files) in Visual Studio, the tab I leave is automatically saved. I don't know if it's coming from VS or one of my extensions, but for the life of me, I can't find a setting to turn it off. Anyone know how?

Here's a list of my extensions:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The VS options dialog has a searchbox. You can try searching for something like "save" and it should point out all option pages containing that keyword

Comment: @derpirscher Yes, I tried that, to no avail.

Comment: Seems that Tweaks has an autosave option https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.Tweaks#autosave

Comment: @derpirscher Looks like that's the one. Make it an answer if you'd like me to mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tweaks extension does have an option for autosaving documents

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.Tweaks#autosave